Harmonic functions on an irreducible finite Markov Chain are constant
On Levin-Peres-Wilmer's book Markov Chain and Mixing Times there's the following Lemma
With $P$ the transition matrix of an homogeneous markov chain over a finite state space $\Omega$,

Lemma 1.16 Suppose that $P$ is irreducible. A function $h$ which is harmonic at every point of $\Omega$ is constant.

Its' proof basically says:

Consider $x_0$ the state where $h(x)$ is maximised
Then every neighbor $z$ of $x_0$ must verify $h(z) = h(x_0)$
Repeating the argument, every state that is reachable in $k$ steps from $x_0$ also evaluates to $h(x_0)$
Since $P$ is irreducible, every state is reachable in a finite amount of steps, therefore $h$ is constant in $\Omega$

I'm stuck on step (2). The proof given in the book states:

Since $\Omega$ is finite, there must be a state $x_0$ such that $h(x_0) = M$ is maximal. If for some state $z$ such that $P (x_0 , z) > 0$ we have $h(z) < M$ , then
$$ h(x_0 ) = P (x_0 , z)h(z) + \sum_{y \neq z} P (x_0 , y)h(y) < M, $$
a contradiction.

I'm not seeing why $h(z) < M$ implies that the sum is $< M$.
If I solve for $h(z)$, I get
$$
  M > h(z)
  = \frac{h(x_0)}{P(x_0, z)} - \frac{\sum_{y \neq z} P (x_0 , y)h(y)}{P(x_0, z)}
  = \frac{M}{P(x_0, z)} - \frac{\sum_{y \neq z} P (x_0 , y)h(y)}{P(x_0, z)}
$$
and this doesn't jump at me like something that must be false

Solving for $h(z)$ is going to make things harder on you. Instead, what we want to argue is that:

Because $h(z) < M$ and $P(x_0, z) > 0$, we have $P(x_0, z) h(z) < P(x_0, z) M$.
For all $y \ne z$, because $h(y) \le M$ and $P(x_0,y) \ge 0$, we have $P(x_0, y) h(z) \le P(x_0, y) M$.

Adding these together, we get
$$
    h(x_0) = P(x_0,z) h(z) + \sum_{y \ne z} P(x_0,y) h(y) < P(x_0,z) M + \sum_{y \ne z} P(x_0,y) M.
$$
Combining the terms to get a sum over all $y$, including $z$, we get
$$
    h(x_0) < \sum_{y} P(x_0,y)M = M.
$$
But $M < M$ is a contradiction.
